# Sybase IQ: How to create a DBSPACE with raw device?

Tags: linux, device, tablespace, sap-iq

I'm on Sybase Iq 15.1 and try to add a dbspace to a demo database, using a raw device on Linux. I always get SQL error 1010000, file already exists:

CREATE DBSPACE KLMTEST USING FILE DF1 '/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-1HITACHI_730109670008' IQ STORE;

Could not execute statement.
The file '/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-1HITACHI_730109670008' already exists.
-- (st_database.cxx 2215)
SQLCODE=-1010000, ODBC 3 State="HY000"
Line 1, column 1

For my understanding, the raw device has to exist BEFORE the Db can use it. How can I specify the raw device's name in order to make the command work?

Permissions of the device are 770 for the sybase user.

Thanks a lot
Martin

Answer (score 1):

The solution is: Using devices directly does not work. Sybase IQ depends on the /dev/raw/rawX structure:

Create it like that:

> create dbspace klmtest using file
>   klmtest1 '/dev/raw/raw1' IQ store;

Make sure, that /dev/rawctl is readable for the sybase user as well!

Good Luck
Martin